# Bat file in windows for chess engine

Tags: batch-file

This is the first time I am creating a batch file. I want to run a chess program using graphical interface. Creator of this program wrote:

> Sunfish' can communicate through the XBoard/CECP protocol by the command pypy -u xboard.py.

So I am wondering how can I make this work. I thought of something like this:

```
@ECHO
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python -u xboard.py
PAUSE
```

However it brings error:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Maybe somethins is wrong with the directory I gave? My python app is under this directory `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe`

Here is the [link](https://github.com/thomasahle/sunfish) to chess program I want to run, under the run section it is written what I wrote here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please do your research before asking a question. All of this information is easily available by just reading the 'Run it!' section of the 'README.md' and a quick Google search.**

---

You need to point to the `python.exe`, because pointing to the directory alone isn't going to work.

However, it is recommended to run this with [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) instead of Python ([read more on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28445290/9248774)). If you want to run it with Python anyway, have a look at [this](http://www.talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?topic_view=threads&p=560462).

Also `username` alone is just a string, what you need is `%UserName%` which is the variable that contains the username:

```
C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -u xboard.py
```

Alternatively you can just use `%LocalAppData%` which is the same as `C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local`:

```
%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -u xboard.py
```

There's a list with the environment path variables over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/217506/868077).