# cannot run python file using pypy

Tags: performance, shell, pypy

Hi everyone I am trying to run a python file (developed in spyder) through the command prompt  (my os is windows 10) and i cannot run it. For this reason I have two questions:
A)am I doing something wrong?
B)is there an easier way to run the python file, such as applying it directly in the pypy3.exe?
I am not a skilled programmer and this is the first time that i have used the command prompt

What I have tried is:

1- I have downloaded pypy from : https://www.pypy.org/download.html

2- I've unzipped the file in my c folder, and added the path to my environment variables (user and not system), the path is C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.5-win64

3-so i have tried to run a file locaded in the folder "C:\Users\acpf9\Desktop\Files" named as "script"
4- i've oppened the "command prompt"
5- oppened the folder wrote:"cd desktop/Files"
6- runned the file using python and it worked as expected wrote:"python script.py"
7-  when i tried to use pypy, i have wrote:" pypy script.py" or "pypy3 script.py" and i have
always go the meassage:

```
 "'pypy3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch 
  file."
                         or
 "'pypy3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."
```

Best regards and many thanks for helping!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893317/how-to-use-pypy-on-windows

Comment: the question is similar and i have made all the steps of the refered post and I still have the same problem. Possibly new solutions might be found by users, since the post is 9 years old

Comment: Just validate your pypy directory in PATH environment variable.
echo %PATH%

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path in the system. Please follow these steps:

1. Open the Control Panel and navigate to System.
2. Click on Advanced system settings in the upper left panel.
3. Click on Environment Variables.
4. Under System Variables, scroll down then double-click the PATH variable.
5. Click New, and add the directory where PyPy is installed, e.g. `C:\PyPy`
6. Select OK.

Hope it helps.